# How to close or dismiss an Outlook Reminder via Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, dismiss, reminders

I want to run a Macro in Outlook at a certain time and so I'm using the Outlook Reminders to do it.  I have written the below code, which successfully runs the Macro but after it has finished the If statement, it then pops up the reminder which I don't need to see and so therefore need to close/dismiss it.

```
Public Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
If Item.Subject = "Refresh Data Test" Then
    Call RunExcelMacros.TestRun
End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone help suggest how I can dismiss the reminder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it - the below seems to work, all code is setup in the "ThisOutlookSession" Module:

```
Private WithEvents OutlookReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Public Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Set OutlookReminders = Outlook.Reminders
If Item.Subject = "Refresh Data Test" Then
    Call RunExcelMacros.TestRun
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OutlookReminders_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim OutlookReminder As Reminder
'After the "Application_Reminder" has run it will then run this code straight after which stops the reminder from actually popping up
    For Each OutlookReminder In OutlookReminders
        If OutlookReminder.Caption = "Refresh Data Test" Then
            If OutlookReminder.IsVisible Then
                OutlookReminder.Dismiss
                Cancel = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next OutlookReminder
End Sub
```